# Are пырей and перо somehow connected?

Tags: этимология

Are пырей and перо somehow connected?

**UPDATE**

Some material from PIE:

***pulos*** a single hair of the human body

***poums*** body hair

***peumos*** adult (having hair)

***peuqs*** tail (> Eng. fox)

***peuros*** wheat

***putos*** vulva (> Eng. pussy)

I wonder cannot the ***peuros*** for wheat derive from "hair"? The proposed derivation by Quassnoi from "fire" looks unlikely to me because the word for bonfire would be ***pea̯ur***, having another root (am I wrong?).

On the other hand, even if Eng. *feather* is traditionally derived from ***peta̯trom*** (a root meaning "fly"), why it cannot be derived from something like ***peutrom***? The etymology of *перо* according to Vasmer is uncertain, but why it could not also derive from ***peutrom*** or hypothetic ***peuros***/***peurom***? If so, then it directly coincides with the word for wheat.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where do you take those reconstructions from?

Answer (score 2):

According to [wiki dictionary](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9), "пырей" derives from a proto-slavic ["пыро"](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/churchslav/7034/%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%BE), which means among other things, "мука" (flour). Another word derived from "пыро" appear to be "пирог".

According to [this page](http://luzhok.ru/magic/health/art2422.html)

> Наши предки не гнушались приготовлением из сушеных корневищ пырея муки, из которой пекли вкусный и полезный хлеб.
>
> (Our ancestors did not shun using dried roots of bluegrass to make flour, from which they baked tasty and wholesome bread).

so "пырей" and "flour" appear to be related.

Answer (score 0):

According to Vasmer, *пырей* (the plant) originates from a word akin to Greek *πυρήνας* ("kernel, core"). The latter may have originated from PIE **paəw̥r* ("fire").

*Перо* originates from PIE **pet-* ("to rush, fly"), and is akin to English "feather" and "fern". The Russian word for "fern", *папоротник*, is also related.

I would not say that *пырей* and *перо* are related.

Comment: See my update. I have added some considerations.